# YouTubeブランドアカウント（複数）の限定公開のライブ配信を取得する方法について

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube

**YouTubeパートナープログラムを使わずに，個人アカウントのトークンで関連する複数のブランドアカウントの限定公開の映像をとってくるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか．**

自作のWebアプリにて，Googleの個人アカウントでログインしたユーザーに紐付けられた複数のYouTubeブランドアカウントの限定公開の映像を取得したいと考えています．ただ，この機能を実装するにあたり，個人アカウントの認証トークンではブランドアカウントの限定公開の映像を取得できず躓いています．利用者にブランドアカウントで直接ログインしてもらえば，限定公開の映像をとってくることはできますが，ブランドアカウントが複数ある場合にすべてのブランドアカウントでログインしてもらわなくても済むよう，できれば個人アカウントで関連するブランドアカウントの限定公開の映像をとれたらなと考えています．

YouTube Data APIのリファレンスを見ますと，Searchリクエスト等には「onBehalfOfContentOwner」というクエリパラメーターがあります．これを使えばログインユーザーのトークンでブランドアカウントの限定公開の映像をとってこれるかもしれませんが，YouTubeパートナープログラムに申し込む必要があるとのことから敷居が高く，これ以外の方法で実装をしたいです．

YouTubeパートナープログラムを使わずに，個人アカウントのトークンを用いて関連するブランドアカウントの限定公開の映像を取得するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか．個人アカウントの認証トークンから，ブランドアカウントの限定公開の映像を直接取得する，あるいは利用者の操作なしにブランドアカウントの認証トークンを取得する方法など，なにか良い方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けませんでしょうか．

**補足**
「利用者」、「自作のWebアプリ」、「ブランドアカウント」の3者の関係は下記の通りになります。

- 「利用者」と「ブランドアカウント」

  ここでのブランドアカウントは利用者がYouTubeの「設定」>「チャンネルの追加または管理する」から作成し所有しているものです。1人の利用者が1つ以上ブランドアカウントを持っているという感じです
- 「利用者」と「自作のWebアプリ」

  Webアプリの利用者はGoogleアカウントを持っている特定の個人であり、私自身ではありません。OAuth認証を使い、Webアプリ（私）は利用者に対し、YouTubeの情報（ここでは限定公開の動画）へのアクセス許可をいただきます。
- 「ブランドアカウント」と「自作のWebアプリ」

  自作のWebアプリにログインした利用者のブランドアカウントから限定公開の動画を取得したいと考えております。

  「利用者にブランドアカウントで直接ログインしてもらえば」というのは、OAuth認証の際アカウントを選択後にYouTubeチャンネルの一覧が出ますので、そこでブランドアカウントを選択してログインして頂くという感じです。

Comment: これは、プログラムに関する質問ですか？　有償コンテンツを違法に視聴しようとする犯罪行為のような感じを受けるのですが。

Comment: 少なくとも「ブランドアカウント」「自作のwebアプリ(=あなた)」「利用者」の三者がいるはずですが、これらの関係性を明確にした方がよさそうです。 / "限定公開の動画" はあなたが適切な権限を持っているのかどうか、ブランドアカウントは主に配信側の話だと思うので、「利用者にブランドアカウントで直接ログインしてもらえば」という部分も違和感を感じます。

Comment: @Fumu7 コメントいただきありがとうございます。上記の質問はYouTubeパートナープログラムではなく、プログラム（Webアプリ）に関するものというつもりです。YouTube Studioの中で自由に関連するYouTubeアカウントを切り替えれるため、素人ながらに個人アカウントのトークンからブランドアカウントのトークンや情報をとってこれる方法があるのではないかと思いこの質問をさせていただきました。@Fumi7さんが上記の質問を受けて犯罪行為という印象を受けられたということは重く受け止めております。ご指摘くださり誠にありがとうございます。

Comment: @cubick コメントいただきありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいた3者の関係について質問本文に補足を追加致しました。ご参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms&hl=ja&gl=JP YouTube利用規約の許可と制限事項の項目を読む限り、禁止項目に引っかかりそうに見えます。

Comment: @radian コメントいただきありがとうございます。リンク先のページを拝見しました。おっしゃるとおり禁止項目（個人的に項目2）に引っかかりそうな気がいたしました。役立つ情報を提供してくださりありがとうございます。